# Adding a method to an object

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue with adding a method to an object in javascript. The following code should return a number but instead returns NaN. Hope you can help

```
function people(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.numYearsLeft = pension();
}

function pension(){
    numYears = 65 - this.age;
    return numYears;
}

var andrews = new people("Andrews Green", 28);

console.log(andrews.numYearsLeft);
```

Comment: because pension has nothing to do with people. `console.log(this)`

Comment: `this` is a keyword that refers to the current context. Within your `pension` function, `this.age === window.age`, _not_ `people.age`.

Comment: Side note- convention would have you define the `people` function as `Person`. Function names beginning with a capital letter indicate that they are constructor functions (functions you can call with the `new` keyword to create a new instance of the constructor). Creating a new "Person" also just makes more grammatical sense than creating a new "People".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a **prototypal** model - making `pension` a **Method** of `people`:

```
function people(name, age){
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.numYearsLeft = this.pension();  // note the `this`
}

people.prototype.pension = function(){ // note the `prototype`
  var numYears = 65 - this.age;
  return numYears;
};

var andrews = new people("Andrews Green", 28);

console.log(andrews.numYearsLeft);     // 37
```

Using `prototype` your `pension` method will inherit the constructor's (`people`) properties (allowing you to refer using the `this` keyword).
Another benefit of this is that, on every `new` instantiation of `people` you'll not recreate new instances / recalls of the `pension` method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: Hi. thanks a lot. I did not know " prototype " ; Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript works on a "function scope", so in short you're in the wrong scope. You need to either bind the "this" variable or create a function on the people class using the prototype property.

You can define it as a prototype function instead

```
people.prototype.pension = function() {
    numYears = 65 - this.age;
    return numYears;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add a console.log() line inside of pension you will see that `this` is the window and not the people object. One way to change `this` would be to use call().

```
this.numYearsLeft = pension.call(this);
```

Example:

```js
function people(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.numYearsLeft = pension.call(this);

}

function pension() {
  numYears = 65 - this.age;
  return numYears;
}

var andrews = new people("Andrews Green", 28);

console.log(andrews.numYearsLeft);
```

Other option is make it part of the people prototype.

```js
function people(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.numYearsLeft = this.pension();

}

people.prototype.pension = function () {
  numYears = 65 - this.age;
  return numYears;
}

var andrews = new people("Andrews Green", 28);

console.log(andrews.numYearsLeft);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to call a function you need to put (). `console.log(andrews.numYearsLeft);` should be `console.log(andrews.numYearsLeft());`

Also on

```
function pension(){
numYears = 65 - this.age;
return numYears;
}
```

this.age is undefined, thus the NaN.

(EDITED) Maybe try:

```
function people(name, age){
    var that = this;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.numYearsLeft = function(){
        numYears = 65 - that.age;
        return numYears;
    };
}
var andrews = new people("Andrews Green", 28);
console.log(andrews.numYearsLeft());
```

Comment: Calling `andrews.numYearsLeft()` throws an error because `numYearsLeft` is not a function, but a reference to the result of calling `pension()`.